# matlab subtracting array from number

Tags: arrays, matlab

this is my second question, so please tell me, if I can improve the way of asking.

I have an array with angles, named 'degree0'. Now I want to calculate (1 - cos(degree)). Therefor I was using two options:

Method 1:

```
mincosd0 = 1 - cosd(degree0);
```

Method 2:

```
for i=1:size(degree0)
mincosd0(i) = (1 - cosd(degree0(i)));
end
```

As far as I understood the way Matlab works with arrays, these two pieces of code should do the same thing. 
But the result I get in each case (when calculating a probability deviation for mincosd0) looks different, and I can't tell, why there is a difference or which way is the correct way to calculate this.

This is the code for the plot, but it's the same in both cases:

```
r2 = pi/500:2*pi/500:2*pi-pi/500; 
mincosx2 = sort((1-cos(r2))); % locations in the centre of each bin

[N20,edges20] = histcounts(mincosd0,'NumBins',500,'BinEdges', 0:2/500:2);
for n = 1:500,  prob1cos(n) = N20(n)/numel(degree0);  end
plot (mincosx2,prob1cos);
```

If you are very sure, that this must do the same thing, I am also thankful for that information, then somewhere else interesting things are happening.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

```
a = rand(3,1);
for i = 1:size(a), fprintf('%g ', i); end % gives 1 2 3 as expected

a = rand(1,3);
for i = 1:size(a), fprintf('%g ', i); end % gives only 1
```

function *size* returns two values even for a vector. You should use *numel* rather than *size* as loop variable, so you can avoid this kind of problem.

By the way, this is because you are using wrong function. It does nothing to do with subtraction of array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This could have been a reason, but I tried to use numel instead, and nothing changed.
If you are sure, that there is no mistake in the first method, I will just go on using that one.